# All values of radio button not get when selected via jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My jQuery function is this:

```
$(function() {
     $('#small').click(function() {
             var selectedRB = $('input[name=radioGroup]:checked').val();
         alert(selectedRB);
     });
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="small" name="radioGroup" value="small" checked><label for="inpSmall">Small</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="small" name="radioGroup" value="medium"><label for="inpMedium">Medium</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="small" name="radioGroup" value="large"><label for="inpLarge">Large</label><br><br>
```

I have the problem that I only got first value, small, when I click on other button it does not return a value.

Comment: May have to put a bind? Pretty uninformative question too.

Comment: The problem is the id you can't use a id twice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

The problem is that you use an id `small`. Id's must be unique in your document. Use `class` instead. Check out my sample and this [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBWsk/).

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<input type="radio" class="small" name="radioGroup" value="small" checked><label for="inpSmall">Small</label><br>

<input type="radio" class="small" name="radioGroup" value="medium"><label for="inpMedium">Medium</label><br>

<input type="radio" class="small" name="radioGroup" value="large"><label for="inpLarge">Large</label><br><br>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
     $('.small').click(function() {

               var selectedRB = $('input[name=radioGroup]:checked').val();
               alert(selectedRB);
       });
})
```

#### More Information

- **[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBWsk/)**
- [HTML id Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Comment: now i want to retrive this value for my sql query at same page how can i retrice this ?

Answer (score 0):

ID is unique, you can't give the same ID to several elements.
Try this:

```
$('input[name=radioGroup]').change(function() {     
    var selectedRB = $('input[name=radioGroup]:checked').val();
    alert(selectedRB);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add some class to your radio buttons like class="someClass"
$(function() {
     $('.someClass').click(function() {     
            var selectedRB = $('input[name=radioGroup]:checked').val();
        alert(selectedRB);
     });
})
```

Comment: Why would he need an additional class if he can use the name of the radio group?